# How to update a table in database using LINQ in F#?

Tags: linq, f#

I have seen plenty of examples on how to query the database but nothing on how to update records. Below is the simple code that I wrote to retrieve a table, but can someone explain me how can I modify a field, say lastActiveDate, and update the table on the database

Thank you,
suday

```
open System
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq

let connString = "Server=localhost;Database=myDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
let db = new MyDb(connString)
db.Log <- System.Console.Out

let res =
    Query.query <@ seq {
        for users in db.userAccounts do
        yield users
     } @>
     |> List.ofSeq

printfn "Totla users: %d" res.Length
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since MyDB is a System.Data.Linq.DataContext, it tracks each object that it loads.  Simply acquire an instance from MyDB, set a property's value on that instance, and call MyDB.SubmitChanges

Comment: Thanks for your response David. I was reading the article "Using LINQ to SQL" (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) and found the same solution as yours. I tried it out and it worked perfectly

Comment: Curioulsy - what is the sql the objects submit back to the server?

Comment: It's typically an UPDATE statement using optimistic concurrency... UPDATE TableName
SET columnName = value, columnName = value (foreach changed value)
WHERE columnName = originalValue and columnName = originalValue (foreach original value)

Answer (score -3):

LInQ (in any .NET language) is not used for doing insert/update/delete operations. After all, it Language Integrated *Query*. That having been said, in your example the `db` value should have methods for passing modified objects back to the database for persistence.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I found some methods in the form of updateXXX (XXX instance);. I am assuming this is what you are referring to.

I am totally new to the world of .NET, so forgive me for asking dumb questions

Comment: Yes! Those are exactly the methods I meant. I would have been more specific, but its been more than a year since I've done LInQ-to-SQL.

Comment: VITA ORM does that `Full LINQ support for database querying. And not only SELECTs - you can use LINQ expressions to execute INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements.`