# F# and ORM tool

Tags: orm, f#

I would like to know your best experiences with F# and ORM tool. Is F# + LINQ 2 SQL having some [intricacies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914785/how-to-update-a-table-in-database-using-linq-in-f)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the current version, the F# support for LINQ is not as smooth as in C#, but it can be used pretty well. I used F# + LINQ to SQL when implementing [F# Snippets Web](http://www.fssnip.net) and was able to write almost everything using F#. There are even some nice features that you don't get in C#.

The syntax for basic queries is based on quoted sequence expressions:

```
let q = <@ seq { for c in db.Customers do
                   if c.Country = "UK" then yield c.Name } @>
```

A nice thing in F# is that you can use *quotation splicing* to refactor your code:

```
let ukCustomers = 
  <@ seq { for c in db.Customers do 
             if c.Country = "OK" then yield c } @>

// Select names of all UK customers
let q = <@ seq { for c in %ukCustomers -> c.Name }
```

Regarding the limitations of F# support:

- I don't think there are any issues with updates (as implied in the linked question).
- Perhaps the largest limitation of the current version is that it has only limited support for nesting of queries (e.g. using `Seq.filter` inside body of `for` loop), but that should be fixed in next version of [PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/) (in fact, if you compile it from source, you may get it already)
- If you can choose, I'd recommend using LINQ to SQL instead of LINQ to Entities. LINQ to Entities doesn't work very well with immutable types, so you cannot easily return F# records and F# tuples. Again, this will likely improve in the future (I did some work on this recently and you can find an initial support in F# PowerPack sources)